# Create a directory on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, directory

I want to know how to create a directory on a specified path.
I used "system("path of directory");" this is work fine in Simulator but not on Device

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Actually i want to use this command "chmod + x /Path of directory/".so 
i use System("chmod +x /Path of File/"); this is work fine on simulator but not on Device

Answer (score 8):

To create a new directory in your apps library directory use this...

```
// Generate the path to the new directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *newDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/new", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];

// Check if the directory already exists
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:newDirectory]) {
    // Directory does not exist so create it
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:newDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can you guide me how to save data in that particular directory.

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:

Answer (score 2):

The `createDirectoryAtPath:attributes: method` has been deprecated.

Use `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` instead.